# SSLのためにJKS形式ののキーストアを作りたい

Tags: java, ssl, spark

Java Spark（jettyの方）で読み込ませられるキーストアを作成したいのですが、方法が分かりません。
SSLは初めてで理解できていないので意味不明なことを言っていたらすいません。
正しいと思う内容で解釈していただければと思います。

ジオトラストラピッドSSLにて取得済みのため、現在手元にあるのは
**・サーバーキー（server.key）**
**・サーバー証明（server.crt）**

**・ジオトラスト中間証明（chain.crt）**
**・ジオトラストから貰ったサーバー証明（aaa.crt）**
です。

※↑拡張子とファイルの形式が違うとのコメントを頂きました。
誤解を招かないようにそのコメントだけここに引用して後で修正しておきます。

> aaa.crt がサーバー証明書
>   server.crt は拡張子が .crt ですが、中身は CSR aaa.crt があれば必要ありません。

これらファイルからキーストアファイル（JKS形式？）を作成したいのですがさっぱり分かりません。

１つのkeystoreファイルをプログラムで読み込めがSSLが使えるようになるようにしてくて、（Sparkではそうでないといけない）
上記ファイルを元に１つのkeystoreファイルを作りたいです

一度pkcs12にして、そこからkeystoneに変換しようとして以下を試しました。
**・chain.crt　と　aaa.crt　を結合（multiple.crt）**
pkcsを作成するために以下のコマンドを実行しました。

```
openssl pkcs12 -inkey server.key -in multiple.crt -export -out super.pkcs12 -nodes -nocerts
```

（最後の「-nodes -nocerts」をつけないと「No certificate matches private key」というエラーが発生しました。）

それをkeystore（JKS?)に変換しようとして下を実行しました

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore super.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystone
```

すると「keytoolエラー: java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input」というエラーが出て先に進めないです。

---

追記
server.crtは
BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST

chain.crtは
BEGIN CERTIFICATE

これらを結合した「server_chain.crt」はただ単に両方をテキストで結合しただけです

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
>   xxxx
>   -----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
>
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>   xxxx
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----

---

追記（本題ではないがこれも多いかと、、、）
これら方法でキーストアファイルを作ってもプログラムで読み込むと「Cannot recover key」というエラーが出る可能性があります。（プログラムによっては必ず）
Java Sparkの場合ですが、キーストアファイルを指定するメソッドにはキーストアファイルのパスワードしか入力するところがありません。
キーストア内のエイリアスのパスワード？とキーストアのパスワードを同じにする必要があります。
（エイリアス名、入力パスなどはこの質問のベストアンサーから）

```
keytool -keypasswd -keystore keystore  -alias myserver
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

openssl pkcs12 コマンドのオプションに `-chain` が必要なのではないでしょうか。

```
openssl pkcs12 -inkey server.key -in server+chain.crt -export -out super.pkcs12 -name myserver -CAfile aaa.crt -caname root -chain
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore super.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcalias myserver -destkeystore keystore -deststoretype JKS
```

#### 訂正、まとめ

すみません、読み違えました。aaa.crt がサーバー証明書なのですね。

```
openssl pkcs12 -inkey server.key -in aaa+chain.crt -export -out super.pkcs12 -name myserver
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore super.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcalias myserver -destkeystore keystore -deststoretype JKS
```

Comment: 回答有り難うございます。
やはり２つめで「keytoolエラー: java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input」と出てしまいます。

また、１つめでもchainをつけてもエラーが出るのは変わらないため「-nodes -nocerts」を追加して実行致しました。

Comment: 確認なのですが、server+chain.crtとは今本文に追記編集致しましたものでよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: すみません、読み違えました。aaa.crt がサーバー証明書なのですね。
server.crt は拡張子が .crt ですが、中身は CSR のようですので、aaa.crt があれば必要ありません。
「openssl pkcs12 -inkey server.key -in aaa.crt -export -out super.pkcs12 -name myserver -CAfile chain.crt -caname root -chain」でどうでしょうか？

Comment: 私の無知で手間をかけてしまいすいません…
今度は「Error unable to get issuer certificate getting chain.」というエラーが出るようになってしまいました。
chainファイルはhttps://www.geotrust.co.jp/resources/rapidssl/repository/intermediate_sha2.html#bからダウンロードしたものです（最近発行したので下の方です）

エラーを調べてみてもあまりヒットせず、私の初心者ミスだと思われるのですがなにか怪しい点などあればお願いします。。。

Comment: 「openssl x509 -in aaa.crt -noout -issuer」と「openssl x509 -in chain.crt -noout -subject」が合っていないようです。
「openssl x509 -in aaa.crt -noout -issuer」の CN (Common Name)に合う中間証明書をダウンロードして試してみてください。

Comment: ご提示いただいたコマンドを実行してみたところ「issuer= /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA」「subject= /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA」と同じと思われる内容が出力されましたが中間証明自体はあっているということでしょうか？

Comment: 合っていますね。-CAfile には中間証明書ではなく、root 証明書が必要のようです。
サーバー証明書と中間証明書をくっつけて、「openssl pkcs12 -inkey server.key -in aaa+chain.crt -export -out super.pkcs12 -name myserver 」でどうでしょうか？

Comment: 出来ました！！納期やばくてほんと命の恩人です！ありがとうございます！！

Comment: Taichiさん、コメントを追わなくても最終的な解決策がわかるように、まとめを回答に反映していただけませんか？